# Var is undefined

Tags: javascript

Hi guys^ have such code:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
var array = [];
$.get("http://wisepla3nt.com/331.txt", 
       function(data) {
           array = data.split(/\r\n|\r|\n/)
       }
);
</script>
<script>alert(array[Math.floor(Math.random()*array.length)]);</script>
</body>
</html>
```

On alert have undefined. Why? array is global.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to return the response from an AJAX call?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-ajax-call)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The function you pass to `get` is not executed immediately. It is assigned as an event handler and fires when the browser gets a response to the HTTP request.

The response doesn't arrive until after the alert statement has fired.

Do the work that depends on the response *in the callback function*.

Answer (score 1):

Probably because you're alerting before your $.get function has returned.

The $.get method is an Ajax call which means it's asynchronous. Try moving your alert code into the callback method.

Answer (score 0):

`get` is asynchronous and you're calling `alert` right after it and before the response comes from a server

So the `array` is empty, `array.length` is zero and `Math.random()*0` will return `0` but there's no `array[0]` so it returns `undefined`

Answer (score 0):

Move alert() right after array filling string.

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
var array = [];
$.get("http://wiseplant.com/1.txt",
       function(data) {
           array = data.split(/\r\n|\r|\n/)
           alert(array[Math.floor(Math.random()*array.length)]);
       }
);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```